# Surface Pro 5 hangs when notification prompt occurs

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Surface Pro 5 
With Windows version : 1803 (17134.1)

When I click on Microsoft Teams or when the "notification center" slides on a popup about a new email. The notification popup gets stuck half on / half off the screen and the mouse and keyboard no longer work.

I have to press the button at the top of the laptop to lock and unlock to allow me to continue working.

I have tried installing the latest feature pack, but this makes no difference.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

---

disabling notifications : no effect, still hangs.

System Event viewer: nothing that stands out compared to another windows 10 machine.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode with Networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A windows update to the latest Fix pack resolved this.

Seem my company was way behind the curve on fixes.